# Text using task on the left of an image

Tags: graphics, columns, text

How can I write something like this in Latex, I use task command to enumerate things.[image]

Comment: Use a table, a minipage environment, a two-column, Tikz, \hspace and \stretch, etc. There are many ways t do it. What have you tried? Please post your code. Thank you

Comment: Please post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Isn't the point of tasks to get an enumerated list moving horizontally?  Why not just use an enumerate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `tasks` for this application. I'd use a combination of `enumitem` and `varwidth` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,height=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),itemsep=3ex]
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=1$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f(x)=-2$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+} f(x)=-\infty$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=\infty$
\item $f(-3)=2$
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note: `height=0.6\textwidth` is just to make the picture square like in your image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using minipages.  If your images are acutal size, they would be:

```
\begin{minipage}{4.25in}
\includegraphics{filename}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{6pt}
\begin{minipage}{1.5in}
\includegraphics{filename} (or display math mode for each line).
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Please don't just code fragments. A small, but compilable test file would be much better as it allows users, looking for a solution, to quickly test your code and see if it works for them. They also wouldn't have to guess which packages are necessary to compile your code.